# Liferay: Custom Role to Add Specific Portlet

Tags: liferay

I've created a Regular User Role in my Liferay Portal titled **Announcement Poster** - the purpose of this role is to give all normal, non-administrative users the ability to add *only* the **Announcement** and the **Alert** Liferay out-of-the-box portlets to a page, as well as modify and delete those portlets as needed.

According to [this post](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/14014942) pertaining to Liferay 6.1, this can be done very simply by defining a Role's permissions and I've seen other users have success with the method, however in Liferay 6.2 I cannot achieve this - With my current settings, the user can still see the Edit and Preview options as well as the Portlet Configuration option. I simply want only the Add option to be displayed to a user assigned to this role.

[image]

My defined role permissions are as follows:

[image]
So far I've tried many combinations of Site, Site Setting & Application permissions but can't achieve the desired outcome; has anyone had any luck with this or a similar situation?

Subsequent Liferay forum post https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/43455741

Comment: Might be a LR bug. Have you checked the LR forums?

Comment: I was trying to post but their cdn is down and the entire site isn't rendering properly, at least from my end

Comment: Posted to LR - link added

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664282/how-to-customize-which-portlets-to-show-in-add-more-portlets-menu this may serve your purpose

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664282/how-to-customize-which-portlets-to-show-in-add-more-portlets-menu) it may serve your purpose

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a Liferay bug, simply those buttons are not under permission system. You can hide them via css, or better, you can hook the dockbar JSP and render them with your own conditions.

> EDIT:

When I say "those buttons are not under permission system" i mean singly.

Comment: I wouldn't want to hide other icons because administrative users need to see them or hook the jsp because that could cause inconsistencies later on (I.e., a user is an Announcement Poster & then granted "Page Theme Modifier" - in which case they would then need to see the Edit button. The condition could grow rather large)